# facebook api with python for friends birthday

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, request

I am trying to retrive my friends bdays. But i get an empty data list like "data": [],
I have user_bday acess token.I am ony using request and json module. My code is

```
    import requests 
    import json

    ACCESS_TOKEN ="xxxxxx..."
    url1='https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends'
    fields = "id,name,birthday"

    url = '%s?fields=%s&access_token=%s' % \
                     (url1,fields, ACCESS_TOKEN,)

    content = requests.get(url).json()
    print content
```

Comment: i get empty list in graph api explorer also

Comment: /me/friends only give you friends that are using the app. That is by design and you can't access birthday from people that are not using you app

Comment: @WizKid Is there any other method to get bdays whoms i can see using my profile without app means using some python code

Comment: Not without breaking Facebook Scraping policies.